# How can I get my wkhtmltopdf footer to display on all pages in my Laravel project with barryvdh package?

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, barryvdh

I have a 20 pages I need to add footer to them using wkhtmltopdf footer-html, but footer not added to all pages.

```
        $footerHtml = view()->make('print.footer', ['job_id' => $job_id])->render();

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('print.page', ["pages" => $pages])->setPaper('a4')
            ->setOption('footer-html', $footerHtml)
            ->setOption('margin-top', 0)
            ->setOption('margin-left', 4)
            ->setOption('margin-right', 4)
            ->setOption('margin-bottom', 35);
```

The footer is showing in small files but in the file with 20 page not showing